# Joining 4 queries

Tags: sql

I have to create a query which on the entry of the user_name should display the responsibilities under that particular user_name. How can I do that?
The tables that should be used are:

```
FND_USER
FND_RESPONSIBILITITY_VL
FND_APPLICATION_VL
FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT
```

Please help...
the username is the mandatory field.

Comment: Please provide more detail (ie, platform, vendor, table definitions, etc.)

Comment: -1.  Without knowing the relationship between the tables, we'd be guessing.  Please remove as much guesswork as possible so that we may answer your question more precisely and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Also give the structure of the tables, at least relevant part of the structure, like the names of the columns.  Look at other questions tagged "sql" to see what kind of information people include in their questions.

Comment: I want the name of the user from the FND_user, the Responsibility name from the FND_responsibility_vl along with start date

Comment: Select * from FND_USER where user_name = :usr;
Select responsibility_id from FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT where user_id = 1014018;
Select * from FND_responsibility_vl;                            Select * from FND_application_vl; these tables should be joined so that when the user name is entered I get the responsibility, application, security and the start date

Comment: I take it you don't know much about databases.  A table has many columns, some of which are used to define how to distinguish records called primary keys, for example in table student, perhaps a good key would be firstname and lastname.  Another type of key determines how they are related to other records in other tables called foreign keys.  We need the primary keys and foreign keys of these tables before we can tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to tell the query which bits of the queries are the same in the tables.

based on your comments this will be a start I think:

```
Select FND_USER.*, FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT.responsibility_id  
FROM FND_USER, FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT  
WHERE user_name = :usr 
AND FND_USER.user_id=FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT.user_id;
```

extrapolating to your other tables (which we don't have any details of) this *might* work, but even if it doesn't it should put you on the right track hopefully:

```
Select FND_USER.*, FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT.responsibility_id, FND_responsibility_vl.*, FND_application_vl.*   
FROM FND_USER, FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT, FND_responsibility_vl, FND_application_vl  
WHERE user_name = :usr 
AND FND_USER.user_id=FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT.user_id
AND FND_USER.user_id=FND_responsibility_vl.user_id
AND FND_USER.user_id=FND_application_vl.user_id;
```

but without more details who knows?

Comment: SELECT fu.user_name,frv.responsibility_name,fa.application_name,decode(fur.security_group_id,0,'Standard',null) security_group,frv.start_date--,fur.*FROM fnd_user fu,fnd_responsibility_vl frv,fnd_user_resp_groups_direct fur,fnd_application_vl fa WHERE fur.user_id=fu.user_id AND fur.responsibility_id=frv.responsibility_id AND fur.responsibility_application_id=fa.application_id AND(sysdate between fu.start_date and nvl(fu.end_date,sysdate))AND(sysdate between frv.start_date and nvl(frv.end_date,sysdate))AND fu.user_name =:usr ANDfrv.responsibility_name = nvl(:resp, frv.responsibility_name);

Comment: This was what I wrote, but it says the bind variable usr and resp are not declared. Is it necessary to declare this? The query worked yest. but now it gives an error. I even tried the query which you suggested but the same error pops up.

Comment: @user1213555 you need to update your question with the code you are using to try and execute the sql, it sounds like you are not setting things up correctly.

Comment: select fu.user_name,frv.responsibility_name,fa.application_name,decode(fur.security_gro‌​up_id,0,'Standard',null) security_group,frv.start_date FROM fnd_user fu,fnd_responsibility_vl frv,fnd_user_resp_groups_direct fur,fnd_application_vl fa WHERE fur.user_id=fu.user_id AND fur.responsibility_id=frv.responsibility_id AND fur.responsibility_application_id=fa.application_id AND(sysdate between fu.start_date and nvl(fu.end_date,sysdate))AND(sysdate between frv.start_date and nvl(frv.end_date,sysdate))AND fu.user_name =:usr ANDfrv.responsibility_name = nvl(:resp, frv.responsibility_name); is code

Comment: @user1213555 no that is the **query** please include the **code** which is executing the **query** in the **question** not as another **comment**, use the edit link to edit your question.

Comment: Thank you Sam.. I could resolve the error.